# KDB Query for OR operator

Tags: kdb

What is the equivalent query in KDB Web:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE (COLA = 'A' AND COLB = 'B') OR (COLA = 'C' AND COLB = 'D')

http://kdbserver:5001/?select fro table where _____________________
```

N.B.: cola and colb are having string datatype

Comment: what are the data types of COLA and COLB? Symbol or string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do:

```
select from table where ((COLA like "string1")&(COLB like "string2"))|((COLA like "string3")&(COLB like "string4"))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select from table where ([]colA;colB) in ([]colA:`A`C;colB:`B`D)
```

Comment: for strings..
select from table where ([]\`$colA;\`$colB) in ([]colA:\`A\`C;colB:\`B\`D)

Comment: How does this perform against the other answers?

Comment: I'm seeing ~2x quicker over a 100m rows

`q)n:100000000;`

`q)tab:([]a:n?\`IBM\`AAPL\`MSFT\`GOOG;b:n?1 2 3 4);`

`q)\ts t1:select from tab where ([]a;b) in ([]a:\`AAPL\`GOOG\`IBM\`IBM\`GOOG;b:1 2 3 4 5);`
`7318 671090016j`

`q)\ts t2:select from tab where ((a like "AAPL")&(b=1))|((a like "GOOG")&(b=2))|((a like "IBM")&(b=3))|((a like "IBM")&(b=4))|((a like "GOOG")&(b=5));`
`12462 536873248j`

`q)r2~r1;`
`1b`

Answer (score 2):

[Connor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35088160/6755893) is right and his answer is quite efficient. Just want to add a version with list operation instead of table:

```
tab:([]cola:("aaa";"bbb";"ccc");colb:("ddd";"eee";"fff"))
select from tab where (flip(cola;colb))in\:(("aaa";"ddd");("bbb";"eee"))
```

Execution speed is almost identical with Connor's one

Answer (score 0):

Sometime I prefer changing type to symbol to get results,
say,

```
tab1:([]a:string 10?`2;b:string 10?`2; c: string 10?`2)
```

--

```
select from tab1 where (((`$a)=`$"ci") & ((`$b)=`$"lf")) or (((`$a)=`$"en") & ((`$b)=`$"dl"))
```

Comment: Note for columns with many uniques, this will bloat the internalized symbol-list of the process